# Bootstrap 4 and Rails 6: $(...).modal is not a function inside ".js.erb" file (but works in other .js files?)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use Bootstrap modals in Rails 6. The modal contains a form that is submitted using Ajax, and I want the modal to hide itself if the form is submitted successfully (but if not, then I modify the contents of the modal to show errors - haven't implemented this part yet). Right now, the form is submitted successfully but I can't hide the modal inside of `create.js.erb` after a successful submit.

In `application.html.erb`:

```html
    <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered align-items-center" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <%= render partial: 'users/register' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In `_register.html.erb`:

```html
<% @user ||= User.new %>
<%= form_with(model: @user, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Register</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body mx-3">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= f.label :user_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_name, class: 'form-control', id: 'userName' %>

    <%= f.label :email_address %>
    <%= f.email_field :email_address, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In `users_controller.rb`:

```rb
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # handle successful save
      log_in @user
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { 
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Commission Marketplace!"
          redirect_to @user 
        }
        format.js {
        }
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

In `create.js.erb`:

```js
$('#navbar').html("<%= j(render 'navbar', data: @data) %>");
$('#registerModal').modal('hide');

// error: $(...).modal is not a function
```

I've also tried to add a plugin to my `custom.js` file like this:

```js
jQuery.fn.hideModal = function() {
    $(this).modal('hide');
    return this;
}
```

And then call `hideModal()` from `create.js.erb`, but then the error becomes `TypeError: $(...).hideModal is not a function`. However, within `custom.js`, the `.modal()` method works fine. It seems like the `create.js.erb` file isn't getting the imports, or something, but I'm not sure how to fix that. I'm using Webpacker with an `environment.js` file that looks like this:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

and in `application.js` I have:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import "bootstrap"
require("./custom")
```

and in the `<head>` section of `application.html.erb`:

```html
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -8, accepted):

It's working now, I just needed to add the script tag for Bootstrap... oops. In case anyone has the same issue, I have the following scripts added just before `</body>` in `application.html.erb`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```